# Collecting image from external site

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a startpage for my browser right now. I would like to put the day's XKCD and place it on my startpage. How can I get the image from xkcd.com and place it on my startpage?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XKCD's official API to do this..

The following link will return a JSON will the url to today's comic

http://xkcd.com/info.0.json

Hope it helps!